# Looking for a GUI application to enter linux commands

Tags: command-line, terminal, console, gui

I am looking for a GUI console where I can enter Linux commands in an entry widget and the result will be output in a text area widget. Is there is such software available? Something like this:

[image]

In console programs like `gnome-terminal` or `xterm`, the screen keeps scrolling with every new command, and I find this annoying specially when the result has a few dozen lines.

I would like to visualize the command and the result at the same time, alike a browser entering a web address in the address bar and obtaining the website as a result.

I am wondering is there is an implementation of such a software in a language like Python, Tcl, Ruby or even Java.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how much better it will be for your purposes, but you could try this:

Open two GUI terminals.  In one ("terminal B"), use `tty` to get the device node; this will be something like `/dev/pts/11`.

In the other ("terminal A"), set output to be redirected to the other terminal:

```
exec 1>&2> /dev/pts/11
```

This will redirect both the standard out (file descriptor 1) and standard error (fd 2) channels.  You may prefer just `exec 1> /dev/pts/11` instead, which will leave the error stream where it is.  This is helpful in distinguishing errors from normal output.

Now in "terminal A" try `ls -l /` or something.  You'll see the output appear in the other terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You can give Launchy a try.  It may have a plugin that integrates with your filesystem and gives the output you're looking for.

Comment: Launchy is for launching programs. I want to be able to see the output from linux commands, like ls or df.